# Order of divergence in square of Dirac delta distribution

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

This question is related to the square of Dirac delta distribution. In one of the answers to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47934/dont-understand-the-integral-over-the-square-of-the-dirac-delta-function), it was argued that if we represent $\delta(x)$ as a limit of a rectangular peak with unit area, width $\epsilon$, and height $1/\epsilon$, we obtain $$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{0}^{\epsilon} [\delta_{\epsilon}(x)]^{2} \mathrm{d}{x} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon}.$$

So, my question is, given a smooth function $f$ satisfying the following properties (so that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} f'(x) = \delta(x)$) $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{for } x \geq \epsilon \\ h(x) &\text{for } 0 < x < \epsilon \\ 0 &\text{for } x \leq 0 \end{cases}$$ where $h(x)$ is some function interpolating the two asymptotic values, can we show that $$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{0}^{\epsilon} [f'(x)]^{2} \mathrm{d}{x} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon}$$ is true without specifying the form of $h(x)$ explicitly?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality applied to $1 = \int_{0}^{\epsilon} f'(x) \, dx $ is probably one way of justifying the divergence.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, unfortunately. But, I think I've found a way. Thanks.

Comment: What I mean is $$ 1 = \left( \int_{0}^{\epsilon} 1 \cdot f'(x) \, dx \right)^2 \leq \left( \int_{0}^{\epsilon} f'(x)^2 \, dx \right)\left( \int_{0}^{\epsilon} 1 \, dx \right) $$ by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. So we have $$\frac{1}{\epsilon} \leq \int_{0}^{\epsilon} f'(x)^2 \, dx. $$ This proof works for any absolutely continuous function interpolating $0$ for $x < 0$ and $1$ for $x > \epsilon$.

Comment: Great. But it doesn't really show how fast the divergence really is. It could be that $$ \int_{0}^{\epsilon} [f'(x)]^{2} \mathrm{d}x \sim \frac{1}{\epsilon^{2}} \quad \text{as} \quad \epsilon \to 0. $$

Comment: Yes, indeed. If we do not specify how a family $\{ f_{\epsilon} : \epsilon > 0 \}$ is constructed, the speed can be made arbitrarily fast by re-parametrizing a given family. For instance, if $\int_{0}^{\epsilon} [f_{\epsilon}'(x)]^2 \, dx \sim \epsilon^{-1}$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+$ then $g_{\epsilon} = f_{\epsilon^2}$ satisfies $$\int_{0}^{\epsilon} g'_{\epsilon}(x) \, dx = 1 \quad \text{and} \quad \int_{0}^{\epsilon} g'_{\epsilon}(x)^2 \, dx \sim \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+$ and similarly for faster speeds.

Comment: Given the definition $ g_{\epsilon} = f_{\epsilon^{2}} $, shouldn't the upper limit of your $g'_{\epsilon}$ integral be $\epsilon^{2}$ instead of $\epsilon$?

Comment: If $\epsilon < 1$, then of course $\epsilon^2$ will work, but the point is that $\epsilon$ also works since $\epsilon > \epsilon^2$ and $g_{\epsilon}'$ vanishes on the interval $[\epsilon^2, \epsilon]$: $$\int_{0}^{\epsilon} g_{\epsilon}(x)' \, dx = \int_{0}^{\epsilon^2} g_{\epsilon}(x)' \, dx = 1. $$ That being said, without knowing the exact construction or at least some property (such as a scaling property under dilation), we cannot tell much.

Comment: Oh yes. $\epsilon > \epsilon^{2}$ for $\epsilon < 1$. Thanks.

Comment: I guess that you are implicitly working on the assumption that $f_{\epsilon}$ is constructed via dilation. Once that point is made explicit then I agree that we will end up with the speed $\sim \text{const}/\epsilon$ as you showed in your solution.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that $f$ is constructed via dilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured out how to show that this is the case (assuming the family of smooth functions considered is constructed via uniform dilation).

Consider a family of smooth functions $$ f_{\epsilon}(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{for } x \geq \epsilon \\ g_{\epsilon}(x) &\text{for } 0 < x < \epsilon \\ 0 &\text{for } x \leq 0 \end{cases} \implies f'_{\epsilon}(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{for } x \geq \epsilon \\ g'_{\epsilon}(x) &\text{for } 0 < x < \epsilon \\ 0 &\text{for } x \leq 0 \end{cases} $$ where $g_{\epsilon}(x)$ is some smooth interpolating function and prime indicates derivative with respect to the argument. When we fix $ \epsilon = r $, we have $$ f_{r}(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{for } x \geq r \\ g_{r}(x) &\text{for } 0 < x < r \\ 0 &\text{for } x \leq 0 \end{cases} \implies f'_{r}(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{for } x \geq r \\ g'_{r}(x) &\text{for } 0 < x < r \\ 0 &\text{for } x \leq 0 \end{cases} $$ and $$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left[ f'_{r}(x) \right]^{p} \mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{r} \left[ g'_{r}(x) \right]^{p} \mathrm{d}x \equiv K_{r}^{p} < \infty$$ for any non-negative integer $p$ since $ g'_{r}(x) $ is necessarily bounded. Otherwise, it is not smooth. Note that some care is required if one is to extend $p$ to rational or real numbers. Note also that, by definition, there is no dependence on $\epsilon$ in $K_{r}^{p}$ as we have already fixed $\epsilon = r$.

Now, we know that $f_{\epsilon}(x)$ is just a strectched version of $f_{r}(x)$. So, we can write $$ f_{\epsilon}(x) = f_{r}(sx) $$ for some stretching function $s$ which, in general, depends on $x$ and $\epsilon$. In our case, however, we would like the stretching to be uniform for all $x$. Thus, we require that $s$ to be independent of $x$. Given the criteria, we have, in particular, that $$ f_{\epsilon}(\epsilon) = f_{r}(s\epsilon) = f_{r}(r). $$ It follows that $s = r/\epsilon$ and $$ f'_{\epsilon}(x) = \frac{r}{\epsilon} f'_{r} \left( \frac{rx}{\epsilon} \right). $$

Thus, \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\epsilon} [g'_{\epsilon}(x)]^{p} \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} [f'_{\epsilon}(x)]^{p} \mathrm{d}x &= \left( \frac{r}{\epsilon} \right)^{p} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left[ f'_{r}\left(\frac{rx}{\epsilon}\right) \right]^{p} \mathrm{d}x \\ &= \left( \frac{r}{\epsilon} \right)^{p} \int_{0}^{\epsilon} \left[ g'_{r}\left(\frac{rx}{\epsilon}\right) \right]^{p} \mathrm{d}x \\ &= \left( \frac{r}{\epsilon} \right)^{p-1} \int_{0}^{r} [g'_{r}(y)]^{p} \mathrm{d}y \\ &= \left( \frac{r}{\epsilon} \right)^{p-1} K_{r}^{p} \end{align} or, written compactly \begin{align} K_{\epsilon}^{p} &= \left( \frac{r}{\epsilon} \right)^{p-1} K_{r}^{p} \\ \implies \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} K_{\epsilon}^{p} &= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left( \frac{r}{\epsilon} \right)^{p-1} K_{r}^{p}. \end{align} In particular, we have the desired result (except for some pre-factor independent of $\epsilon$) when $ p = 2$, that is $$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{0}^{\epsilon} [f'_{\epsilon}(x)]^{2} \mathrm{d}x = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{r}{\epsilon} K_{r}^{2}. $$